# Unable to redirect individual blog posts to new page with their related content - Flask Blog

Tags: python, html, mysql, flask, jinja2

I am building a flask blog application and currently have a more info button under each blog post, which is supposed to redirect to where the blog post content is. However, I am struggling to redirect - the page keeps showing up blank.

Here is a part of my routes.py file

```
@app.route("/moreinfo/<id>", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def moreinfo(id):
    current_post = Job_Requirements.query.filter_by(id=id).first_or_404()
    return render_template('moreinfo.html', title='More Info', current_post=current_post)
```

This is my jobs.html file which has all the jobs/blog posts on it. Below is the more info button at the end which is supposed to redirect you to the content page of each individual post - specified by their id.

```
<!DOCTYPE html> {% extends "layout.html" %} {% block content %} {% for post in posts %}
<article class="media content-section">
    <div class="media-body">
        <div class="article-metadata">
            <a class="mr-2" href="#">{{ post.company }}</a>
            <small class="text-muted">{{ post.date_posted }}</small>
        </div>
        <h2><a class="article-title" href="#">{{ post.job_title }}</a></h2>
        <p class="article-content">{{ post.sector }}</p>
        <p class="article-content">{{ post.location }}</p>
        <p class="article-content">{{ post.employment_type }}</p>
        <a href="{{ url_for('moreinfo', id=post.id)}}" class="btn btn-primary text-right">More Info</a>
    </div>
</article>
{% endfor %} {%endblock content %}
```

Here is my Moreinfo.html file which is what each blog post content is supposed to open up into.

```
<!DOCTYPE html> {% extends "layout.html" %} {% block content %} {% for post in posts %}
<h1>More Info</h1>
<article class="media content-section">
    <p class="article-content">{{ post.description }}</p>
    <ul class="list-unstyled">
        <li>This is a list.</li>
        <li>It appears completely unstyled.</li>
        <li>Structurally, it's still a list.</li>
        <li>However, this style only applies to immediate child elements.</li>
        <li>Requirements:
            <ul>
                <li class="article-content"></li>{{ post.requirement_1 }}</li>
        <li class="article-content"></li>{{ post.requirement_2 }}</li>
        <li class="article-content"></li>{{ post.requirement_3 }}</li>
        <li class="article-content"></li>{{ post.requirement_4 }}</li>
        <li class="article-content"></li>{{ post.requirement_5 }}</li>
        <li class="article-content"></li>{{ post.requirement_6 }}</li>
        <li>will still show a bullet</li>
        <li>and have appropriate left margin</li>
        </ul>
        </li>
        <li>This may still come in handy in some situations.</li>
    </ul>
</article>
{% endfor %} {%endblock content %}
```

Any help would be so appreciated, I have been stuck for so long on how to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

In your Moreinfo.html file you still loop over the variable `posts`, but in the route you give the template the `current_post` directly. As you currently loop over nothing, nothing shows in the browser.

Comment: ahhh okay, so then within my moreinfo.html file - would I do {% for post in current_post %} and then within my route file render_template('moreinfo.html', title='More Info', current_post=current_post)

Comment: actually I have tried  what i just wrote and it doesn't work

Comment: You leave out the loop and, instead of ```post```, use ```current_post```, e.g. ```current_post.description```